# Is this SQL Cluster a CA System or CP System as per CAP Theorem?

Tags: sql, distributed-system

Say I have an SQL Cluster with a leader and followers, and to ensure Strong Consistency across I've incorporated Paxos/Raft along with either a Read-Write Quorum or Distributed Transaction. Is this system a Consistent and Available System or Consistent and Partition Tolerant System?

Comment: What's an _SQL cluster_? Do you mean some kind of database server cluster?

Comment: I mean a set of SQL Databases connected as Nodes and a specific node as a leader.